# How to decrease a 3D matrix to a 2D matrix using Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have built a Keras ConvLSTM neural network, and I want to predict one frame ahead based on a sequence of 10-time steps:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from keras import layers

# We create a layer which take as input movies of shape
# (n_frames, width, height, channels) and returns a movie
# of identical shape.

model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   input_shape=(None, 64, 64, 1),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                   padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3),
               activation='sigmoid',
               padding='same', data_format='channels_last'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta')
```

training:

```
data_train_x = data_4[0:20, 0:10, :, :, :]
data_train_y = data_4[0:20, 10:11, :, :, :]

model.fit(data_train_x, data_train_y, batch_size=10, epochs=1, 
validation_split=0.05)
```

and I test the model:

```
test_x = np.reshape(data_test_x[2,:,:,:,:], [1,10,64,64,1])
next_frame = model.predict(test_x,batch_size=1, verbose=1, steps=None)
```

but the problem is that 'next_frame' shape is: (1, 10, 64, 64, 1) but I wanted it to be of shape (1, 1, 64, 64, 1)

And this is the results of 'model.summary()':

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  59200     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_4 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  115360    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, None, 64, 64, 40)  160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, None, 64, 64, 1)   1081      
=================================================================
Total params: 407,001
Trainable params: 406,681
Non-trainable params: 320
```

So I don't know what layer to add so I decrease the output to 1 frame instead of 10 frames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected based on the 3D convolution in the final layer. For example, if you have 1 filter in a Conv2D across a 3-dimensional tensor, with padding = 'same', this means it will produce a *2D* output of the same height and width (e.g. the filter implicitly also captures along the depth axis).

The same is true for 3D across a 4-dimensional tensor, where it implicitly captures along the channel dimension depth axis, resulting in a 3-D tensor of the same (sequence index, height, width) as the input.

It sounds like what you want to do is add a pooling step of some kind after your Conv3D layer, such that it flattens across the sequence dimension, such as with `AveragePooling3D` with a pooling tuple of `(10, 1, 1)` to average across the first non-batch dimension (or modified according to your specific network needs).

Alternatively, suppose you want to specifically "pool" along the sequence dimension by taking only the final sequence element (e.g. instead of averaging or max-pooling across the sequence). You could then make the final `ConvLSTM2D` layer to have `return_sequences=False`, followed by a 2D convolution in the final step, but this means your final convolution won't benefit from aggregating across a sequence of predicted frames. Probably application-specific whether this is a good idea or not.

Just to confirm the first approach, I added:

```
model.add(layers.AveragePooling3D(pool_size=(10, 1, 1), padding='same'))
```

just after the `Conv3D` layer, and then made toy data:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 10, 64, 64, 1)
```

and then:

```
In [22]: z = model.predict(x)

In [23]: z.shape
Out[23]: (1, 1, 64, 64, 1)
```

You would need to ensure the pooling size in the first non-batch dimension is set to the maximum possible sequence length to ensure you always get (1, 1, ...) in the final output shape.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to ely's  `Conv2D` and `AveragePooling3D` solutions, you can set the last `ConvLSTM2D` layer's `return_sequence` parameter as `True` but change the padding of the `Conv3D` layer to `valid`  then  set its `kernel_size` parameter as `(n_observations - k_steps_to_predict + 1 , 1 , 1)`. With this, you are able to alter the time_dimension(#frames) of the output. You can apply this for any direct k-step ahead prediction assuming that the number of observations are fixed.

Comment: how would you know n_observations in advance?

Comment: She wants to implement 1-step ahead prediction based on 10 previous time steps. Thus, she knows n_observations=10 beforehand. And, I also stated that my solution assumes that the number of observations is fixed.

Comment: yes this worked for me, I interprete `n_observations` as `look back timesteps`. Thanks, your solution helped me